# Flat Array depth nesting

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to nest a flat array to represent an incremental depth level sequence as follows:  `['1'['2'['3'['4'['5']]]]]` from a given string `'1/2/3/4/5'`

so far I have managed to achieve to `[ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' ]` from `str.split('/')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string into an array on "/" then reduce it, right-to-left to a new array where each iteration creates a new array with the number at the start followed by the previous iteration result.

```js
const str = "1/2/3/4/5"

const arr = str.split("/").reduceRight((inner, num) => 
  [ num, [].concat(inner) ])

console.info(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)